# Considerations when running code on muliple nodes in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below code reads a file(example.txt) and calculates the eucleudian distance between each of the points.
example.txt (referenced below) contents are : 
"
a,1
b,1
c,2
"
This code works as expected but for large datasets it is quite slow.
Other than filtering comparisons that are redundant such as (a,b) & (b,a) -> (b,a) comparison is duplicated)

Is there anything I should be aware of ? Currently I'm just running this code on a single node. But to run this on multip nodes are
there considerations I shouuld take into account ?

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;

object first {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")

  val conf = new org.apache.spark.SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local")
    .setAppName("distances")
    .setSparkHome("C:\\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4\\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  def euclDistance(userA: User, userB: User) = {

    val subElements = (userA.features zip userB.features) map {
      m => (m._1 - m._2) * (m._1 - m._2)
    }
    val summed = subElements.sum
    val sqRoot = Math.sqrt(summed)

    println("value is" + sqRoot)
    ((userA.name, userB.name), sqRoot)
  }

  case class User(name: String, features: Vector[Double])

  def createUser(data: String) = {

    val id = data.split(",")(0)
    val splitLine = data.split(",")

    val distanceVector = (splitLine.toList match {
      case h :: t => t
    }).map(m => m.toDouble).toVector

    User(id, distanceVector)

  }

  val dataFile = sc.textFile("c:\\data\\example.txt")
  val users = dataFile.map(m => createUser(m))
  val cart = users.cartesian(users) //
  val distances = cart.map(m => euclDistance(m._1, m._2))
  //> distances  : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), Double)] = MappedR
  //| DD[4] at map at first.scala:46
  val d = distances.collect //

  d.foreach(println) //> ((a,a),0.0)
  //| ((a,b),0.0)
  //| ((a,c),1.0)
  //| ((a,),0.0)
  //| ((b,a),0.0)
  //| ((b,b),0.0)
  //| ((b,c),1.0)
  //| ((b,),0.0)
  //| ((c,a),1.0)
  //| ((c,b),1.0)
  //| ((c,c),0.0)
  //| ((c,),0.0)
  //| ((,a),0.0)
  //| ((,b),0.0)
  //| ((,c),0.0)
  //| ((,),0.0)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark on multiple nodes should run faster without any code changes. You can tweak it to run even faster like any other software system.

For now, you can run your local code run even faster if you just give it more cores.

Change the following to

```
.setMaster("local")
```

to

```
 .setMaster("local[4]") //4 or 8 or 16 depending on how many cores you have on your local machine.
```